# Python [Openpyxl - iterate through each column]

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to browse the entire "B" column of my Excel file,
However, when I tried all the possibilities, I often got the first two columns with the same answer. I have some problems to find the solution even if I use get_letter_column or something else. I want to make in column "A" the name of the Coin and in column "B" the volume.
Here is my code

```py
from tkinter.tix import COLUMN
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from headers import HEADERS
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter as get_idx

book = load_workbook("Crypto.xlsx")
ws = book.active

response = requests.get("https://www.coingecko.com/", headers=HEADERS)
html = response.text

soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
coin_50 = soup.find_all("span", class_="lg:tw-flex font-bold tw-items-center tw-justify-between")[:50]
volume_50 = soup.find_all("span", class_="no-wrap")[:50]

crypto = [crypto.text.replace("\n", "") for crypto in coin_50]
volume = [volume.text for volume in volume_50]

for row in ws.iter_cols(max_row=len(crypto), min_col=1):
    for enum, cell in enumerate(row):
        cell.value = crypto[enum]

for row in ws.iter_cols(max_row=(len(volume)), cols = 2):
    for enum, cell in enumerate(row):
        cell.value = volume[enum]

book.save("Crypto.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work as it you'd need to specify the column to write to in the second loop. I'd expect a syntax error on this line anyway, however you'd need to specify column 2

```
for row in ws.iter_cols(max_row=(len(volume)), cols = 2):
```

change the line to this

```
for row in ws.iter_cols(max_row=(len(volume)), min_col=2, max_col=2):
```

However looping through the rows twice is inefficient, both columns can be updated on the same loop

```
...
crypto = [crypto.text.replace("\n", "") for crypto in coin_50]
volume = [volume.text for volume in volume_50]

for row in ws.iter_cols(max_row=len(crypto), min_col=1):
    for enum, cell in enumerate(row):
        cell.value = crypto[enum]
        ## The next column is an offset from this cell so update it as well
        cell.offset(column=1).value = volume[enum]

## Change the iteration to loop through column B 
# for row in ws.iter_cols(max_row=(len(volume)), min_col=2, max_col=2):
#     for enum, cell in enumerate(row):
#         cell.value = volume[enum]

book.save("Crypto.xlsx")
```